# Creating a .NET website that supports Facebook, Twitter, Google+ OAuth Logins

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to implement OAuth functionality to allow users of an application i'm building to login via Facebook, Twitter, and possibly Google plus. Every post I've found thus far seems to suggest starting from scratch, creating an MVC 4 'Internet Application' project.

What are the relevant references, code snippets, plugins etc which are required to implement this functionality?

**I'm currently using Forms authorization.**

Comment: http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: OAuth is more about authorising a website to act on behalf of the end user; less about being a general authentication mechanism. You might want to look into OpenID instead?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have set up Forms Authentication MVC 4 has built in support for users to authenticate themselves with OpenID and OAuth using an open source project called DotNetOpenAuth, it is a very similar system to forms authentication using cookies and redirects.

These services just need to be configured and this takes place during application start-up. Inside the Application_Start() event there is a call AuthConfig.RegisterAuth(), which contains just commented out code to the third party services.

Before you can use these services you need to register your application with most of them. When you register with a third party you will usually be assigned an appId and an appSecret. You need to insert these values into the code where you register with them as a client.

Google is the one provider commented out who doesn’t require any registration so you can just uncomment the line. OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient(); in the AuthConfig.cs file.

When you rebuild the application and go to the login page you will see on the right there is now a Google button you can press to login through the Google service. This button will re-direct the user to Google where they can sign in with their Google account. Once they have signed in Google will ask the user if they happy for your application to have their e-mail address. The user must answer yes, if they decline this they won’t get logged into your application.

Google will then re-direct back to your application sending some cryptographically sealed and signed parameters so OpenAuth can verify that Google did actually authenticate the user. Once the user is successfully authenticated and logged in, they can create an account by clicking the register button they will be presented with.

There is a link in the comments at the top of the AuthConfig.cs file, which goes to a page telling you how to register with the other third party services. 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252166

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your request to do this "without creating an internet application"....

"Internet application" is a type of project that tells *Visual Studio* what you're using it for.  It's not required by any .NET standard, but if you're using Visual Studio then it's a step you need to take.  Otherwise VS doesn't know if it should help you build a WinForms app, a Console app, WPF, etc...

The other project type you could use would be a WebSite, however if you intend on leveraging .NET than an Internet Application is a the better choice--it assumes your building a website that will be running .NET code.

---

Others have mentioned using DotNetOpenAuth to get your site running; I fully support that, but also wanted to mention the [Social Bootstrap API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) project.  It achieves a similar result, but does so using [ServiceStack.NET](http://www.servicestack.net/).  There's a very good chance you won't want to use it, but it's always good to evaluate alternative options--they can help show you the pros/cons of each other.